# Dataframe same key with multiple values and One Hot Encoding (Python, Pandas)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, one-hot-encoding

I have the following toy dataframe example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 0, 0], 'key':['role', 'role', 'role'], 'val': ['admin', 'local_usr', 'fin_dep_ds']})
```

As you may see the same key has multiple values.
When I pivot the table, the `agg` function I am using is `",".join()` but the final goal is to apply one hot encoding on these values:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.pivot_table(df, \
                            values='val', \
                            index='id', \
                            columns='key', \
                            aggfunc=','.join).to_records())
```

Final goal:

```
id admin local_usr fin_dep_ds
0  1     1         1
```

Please advise how can I do it? Any best practice to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `.pivot_table()` with `aggfunc="size"` produces your result:

```py
x = df.pivot_table(index="id", columns="val", aggfunc="size").reset_index()
x.columns.name = None
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id  admin  fin_dep_ds  local_usr
0   0      1           1          1
```

Comment: Thanks dear Andrej, please explain what size means here? @andrej-kesely

Comment: @SteveS `aggfunc="size"` computes group sizes. `admin`, `local_usr`, `fin_dep_ds` are only 1 time under the `id=0`. More about aggfuncs for example here: https://datascientyst.com/list-aggregation-functions-aggfunc-groupby-pandas/

Comment: You've helped me a lot dear @Andrej-Kesely trying with my df but need a bit more of your assistance please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900963/pivot-dataframe-with-1-to-many-key-value-pairs-along-with-11-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
res = (
    pd.crosstab(index=df.id, columns=df.val)
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

   id  admin  fin_dep_ds  local_usr
0   0      1           1          1
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0, 0, 0], 
    'key':['role', 'role', 'role'], 
    'val': ['admin', 'local_usr', 'fin_dep_ds']
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dear @Rodalm, what is better in terms of performance?

Comment: @SteveS `pd.crosstab` [under the hood calls `DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.2/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L523-L689) with an little extra overhead.  But you shouldn't worry too much, the time difference is negligible.