# Pivot dataframe with 1 to many key value pairs along with 1:1 key value pairs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Here is my toy dataframe example that I am trying to pivot:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1], 'key':['role', 'role', 'role', 'dep', 'country', 'role', 'dep', 'country'], 'val': ['admin', 'local_usr', 'fin_dep_ds', 'fin', 'US', 'kuku', 'security', 'DE']})
df.pivot_table(index="id", columns="val", aggfunc="size", ).reset_index()
```

But the output I get is:

```
    val id  DE  US  admin   fin fin_dep_ds  kuku    local_usr   security
0       0   NaN 1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0         NaN     1.0       NaN
1       1   1.0 NaN NaN     NaN NaN         1.0     NaN       1.0
```

What I want is to transform it to be:

```
id admin local_usr fin_dep_ds kuku country dep
0  1     1         1          0    US      fin
1  0     0         0          1    DE      security
```

Please advise how can I pivot my df to get this result, it seems to me I need to split the df to 2 parts and join - the part with multiple values per key and the 1:1 key value pairs.

Comment: In your output I see `DE` as one country, but in input data `DE` is missing. From where is this `DE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pivot it twice, based on whether the key was repeated:

```py
# Find keys that are repeated more than once for any `id`
idx = df.groupby(["key", "id"]).size().groupby(level=0).max().loc[lambda x: x > 1].index

# We will pivot those keys differently
cond = df["key"].isin(idx)

result = pd.concat([
    df[cond].pivot_table(index="id", columns="val", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0),
    df[~cond].pivot_table(index="id", columns="key", aggfunc="first").droplevel(0, axis=1)
], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: But it can be other keys also. not just role. I am looking for a generic solution where every key that has multiple values will be split to multiple columns and 1:1 key value will create 1 new column and the relevant values will be in this column.

Comment: You can teak the solution a bit to achieve the desired outcome. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["key"] in {"dep", "country"}:
        data.setdefault(row["id"], {})[row["key"]] = row["val"]
    else:
        data.setdefault(row["id"], {})[row["val"]] = 1
    data[row["id"]]["id"] = row["id"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values()).fillna(0).set_index("id")
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda k: k in {"dep", "country"})]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    admin  local_usr  fin_dep_ds  kuku       dep country
id                                                      
0     1.0        1.0         1.0   0.0       fin      US
1     0.0        0.0         0.0   1.0  security      DE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @andrej-kesely, but you are hard coding the dep and country, the main incentive is to create an "engine" that will split to columns that are equal to the values only if the key has multiple values, like role. If not, and the key has only one value, the column will be equal to the key and the value will reside accordingly.